# Omnet++ and Inet framework wrong behavior: sensor nodes with multiple radio transmit on both radios

Tags: simulation, omnet++, inet

Good morning everyone,

I am developing a simulation to analyse the behaviour of a wireless sensor network composed of nodes using 2 wireless radios running at 2 different frequencies (2.4GHz and 6GHz).
In the scenario I envision, some special nodes beacons messages on the 2.4GHz, while the 6GHz radio is off most of the time.
I defined in the .ini file the nodes to have 2 wireless interfaces with the parameter

```
*.host*.numWlanInterfaces = 2
```

and I defined the parameters of the two radios as follows

```
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.typename = "Ieee802154NarrowbandScalarRadio"
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.centerFrequency = 2.4GHz
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.bandwidth = 2MHz
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.power = 1mW       #--> 0dBm
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.preambleDuration = 10us
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 4B
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.receiver.sensitivity = -100dBm
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.receiver.energyDetection = -100dBm
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 0dB

*.host*.wlan[1].radio.typename = "Ieee802154NarrowbandScalarRadio"
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.centerFrequency = 6GHz
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.bandwidth = 500MHz
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.transmitter.power = 1.4mW
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.transmitter.preambleDuration = 10us
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.transmitter.headerLength = 4B
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.receiver.sensitivity = -100dBm
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.receiver.energyDetection = -100dBm
*.host*.wlan[1].radio.receiver.snirThreshold = 0dB
```

I used a slightly modified version of the UDPBasicApp to transmit messages.
All nodes transmit 100 messages (1 message / second) and then the simulation ends.

My problem is that I am not sure I understood how to tell the application to transmit only on one interface, so my statistics in terms of sent and received packets are totally wrong.

I tried getting a pointer to both radios from the .ned module of the application and to swtich off the second radio but this did not seem to work.

I also tried to use different modules to represent the nodes (WirelessHost, AdhocHost, SensorNode) as well as different MAC types, but still no luck: I always find 100 packets transmitted on BOTH the wlan interfaces of the node.

Is there anyone that can help me figuring out how to turn off one of the two radios, so that statistics are not wrong?
Thanks in advance for the help,

Lorenzo